# Getting xmonad to show name of current workspace in xmobar

Tags: xmonad, haskell

New to xmonad/xmobar/haskell, trying to get the name of the current workspace to show up in xmobar. So far I have this xmonad.hs:

```
module Main where
  import XMonad
  import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
  import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
  import XMonad.Actions.WorkspaceNames
  import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
  import XMonad.Prompt
  import XMonad.Util.EZConfig

  main = xmonad =<< xmobar myConfig

  myConfig = defaultConfig { startupHook = setWMName "LG3D" , logHook = myLogHook } `additionalKeys` [ ((mod4Mask, xK_r      ), renameWorkspace defaultXPConfig) ]

  myLogHook = workspaceNamesPP xmobarPP >>= dynamicLogString >>= xmonadPropLog
```

This seems to allow me to change the name of a workspace (at least a prompt with "Workspace name:" appears, and takes my input).

However, xmobar doesn't show the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two different ways to send information to xmobar.

Here :

```
main = xmonad =<< xmobar myConfig
```

You are using the [`xmobar`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#v:xmobar) convenience function. You can click on the source link on the documentation to see how it is defined. It uses the [`statusBar`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#v:statusBar) function to launch xmobar with the default `xmobarPP`. The `statusBar` function uses `spawnPipe` to launch the status bar application, and modifies the `PP` to output to that pipe.

This is the bar you are seeing, with the default pretty printer and logger that only prints the workspaces tags. The `XMonad.Actions.WorkspaceNames` module you are using associates names with workspaces tags. It provides the `workspaceNamesPP` function that combines with a [`PP`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#t:PP) to retrieve the names.

And here :

```
myLogHook = workspaceNamesPP xmobarPP >>= dynamicLogString >>= xmonadPropLog
```

You are using the `workspaceNamesPP` function with `xmobarPP`, you pass the result to `dynamicLogString` that returns the status as a string, and you pass that string to `xmonadPropLog` that writes it as  a `_XMONAD_LOG` property on the root window. This is a different way to communicate the information to xmobar, which can be [configured to read that property](http://projects.haskell.org/xmobar/#other-plugins). In that case, you don't have to launch xmobar from xmonad.

So you should decide which way you want to use.

You can for example keep launching xmobar from XMonad using [`spawnPipe`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-Run.html), and have `myLogHook` write the status to a pipe that you pass to it :

```
import XMonad.Util.Run -- spawnPipe and associated functions

main = xmonad . myConfig =<< spawnPipe "xmobar"

myConfig pipe = defaultConfig { startupHook = setWMName "LG3D" , 
                                logHook = myLogHook pipe} 
                `additionalKeys` 
                 [((mod4Mask, xK_r), renameWorkspace defaultXPConfig)]

myLogHook pipe = workspaceNamesPP xmobarPP {ppOutput = hPutStrLn pipe}
                   >>= dynamicLogWithPP
```

The `statusBar` function also modifies the `manageHook` and `layoutHook` to add the `manageDocks` and `avoidStruts` from the [XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-ManageDocks.html) module to them. You should use this module so that the bar and windows don't step on each other. The `manageDocks` makes XMonad ignore the windows of type dock or desktop. The `avoidStruts` layout modifier changes the layouts to reserve space for the bars, according to their [_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472578320) property.

`manageHook` `layoutHook` and `handleEventHook` are part of [`XConfig`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Core.html#t:XConfig), so to add the function provided by the `XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks` module :

```
 myConfig pipe = defaultConfig 
       { 
        startupHook = setWMName "LG3D" , 
        logHook = myLogHook pipe,
        manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig,
        layoutHook = avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig,
        handleEventHook = docksEventHook <+> handleEventHook defaultConfig
       } `additionalKeys` [((mod4Mask, xK_r), renameWorkspace defaultXPConfig) ]
```

The `xmobar` function you were using also binds the mod + B key shortcut to `sendMessage ToggleStruts` to toggle the bar gaps, so if you want that keybinding you should add it too.

Also :

```
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig
```

You are importing `additionalKeys` from the `XMonad.Util.EZConfig` module, and then you are importing all of the `XMonad.Util.EZConfig` module.

Comment: Thanks! Nearly there. The only weird thing now is that the `xmobar` hides part of the screen (e.g. it hides the menu bar of gnome terminals) which was not happening before.

Comment: Yes, that's because `statusBar` also added the `manageDocks` and `avoidStruts` functions from the XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks module for you. Edited.

Comment: "You should use [XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks] so that the bar and windows don't step on each other." -- trying to, but not sure how to add it to your example.